# Background Image Is Not Covering The Entire Screen

Tags: css

In my CSS file I have the following piece of code but find the screen still not being covered.

The Edge is working good, but with the scroll bars. Footer also visible.

The Internet Explorer has a black portion at the bottom. When I click Alt making the menu items appear, the entire screen fills up and footer becomes visible.

The Google Chrome has an average of the two thus having the footer cut in two.

```
body {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: whitesmoke;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, darkslategrey);
    background: inherit center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: the above code works for me in Chrome, Edge, and internet explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this property to your css:

```
body {
height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `min-height`